# How to configure two hazelcast Cache(ie.,IMap)one for distributed cache and another for single instance cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In my application i would like to have two cache maps

1. One for distributed cache(should be available in all instances of the tcp/ip network for global access

   and another for application specific cache should be available only for this instance.

How to configure this?

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have particular problem with using a standard `Map` implementation (like hash map or concurrent hash map) for that? Would not make a difference and you'd still use the map API...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have to run some modules in multiple instances. In that case how can i maintain the same cache data in all instances?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regular ConcurrentHashMap since IMap in a single instance of Hazelcast is basically a local jvm process that extends it. but if you still need to use Hazelcast specific features on that single instance, you can just set it up as a single member cluster by disabling all [join mechanisms](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-members-by-tcp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have to run some modules in multiple instances. So your idea doesn't solve my problem